# How to embed Javascript function in restful api in php?

Tags: javascript, php, api

I have the following code in one of api files(DispatchJob_Public) and i need ajax here to call the other file(selectDriverForJobResult) after 2 minutes. I can do that in php with sleep(), but that will keep the server busy. Ajax call is at the end of the php code. Can i embed js in api code? Or is there any alternate to do what i am trying to do.

Moreover i have got response from the first file(DispatchJob_Public), but no response from the second file(selectDriverForJobResult) when i called the endpoint in postman. Because the call wasn't made. If the second file was called, it should have return some response. The strange thing is that i get response from second file when i run it in browser. I think that is because the browser supports the javascript but the call made from android to the end point doesn't support that.

Please can i get any solution for this?

```
<?php
include_once ('connection.php');
include_once ('fcm_notification.php');
//error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);


$user_id              = $_REQUEST["user_id"];
$customer_name        = $_REQUEST["customer_name"];
$group_id_fk          = $_REQUEST["group_id_fk"];
$readynow_checkbox    = $_REQUEST["readynow_checkbox"];
$job_points           = '';
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    if(strcasecmp($benefits_type, 'Points') == 0){

        if(strcasecmp($fixed_price, '') == 0){
            $fixed_price_new = $estimated_price;
        }else{
            $fixed_price_new = $fixed_price;
        }

    $sql_job_points = "SELECT `points` FROM `hg_job_points` WHERE '$fixed_price_new' BETWEEN `min_price` AND `max_price`";
    $res_jobPoints = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_job_points);
    $row_job_points   = $res_jobPoints->fetch_assoc();
    $job_points    = $row_job_points["points"];

    }


    if(strcasecmp($commission_percent, 'Amount') != 0 && strcasecmp($fixed_price, '') != 0){

    $commision_price = ($commission_percent / 100) * $fixed_price;

    }

    //insert job in job table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `hg_jobs`(`customer_name`, `pickup_address`, `dropoff_address`, `customer_phone`, `instruction`, 
        `via`, `user_id_fk`, `group_id_fk`, `pickup_time`, `flight_no`, `car_type`, `post_time`) 
        VALUES ('$customer_name', '$pickup_address', '$dropoff_address', '$customer_phone', '$instruction', '$via', '$user_id', '$group_id_fk',
        '$pick_time', '$flight_no', '$car_type', '$date')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        //get job id from jobs table     
        $job_id =  $conn->insert_id;

        //insert new record in advance job table 
        $sql_adv = "INSERT INTO `hg_job_details`(`no_of_passenger`, `no_of_bags`, `child_seats`, 
        `car_type_specific`, `job_type`, `job_price`, `estimated_amount`, `payment_type`, `benefits_type`, `benefit_percent`, 
        `benefit_amount`, `job_points`, `ready_now_job`, `job_id_fk`) 
        VALUES ('$passenger','$bags','$child_seats','$car_type_specific','$job_type','$fixed_price', '$estimated_price',
            '$payment_type','$benefits_type','$commission_percent','$commision_price', '$job_points', '$readynow_checkbox', '$job_id') ";

        $res_adv = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_adv);
        if($res_adv){

            echo json_encode(Array('message' => 'job success'));

            //get black list users
            $sql_black = "SELECT blacklist_user_fk FROM hg_black_list WHERE user_id_fk = '$user_id'";
            $res_black = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_black);

            //if specif type car is any
            if(strcasecmp($car_type_specific, 'ANY') == 0){

                if ($res_black->num_rows > 0) {
                //get all fcm key and send notification (if blacklist table not empty)
                $sql = "SELECT ft.fcm_token from hg_user_notify_token ft 
                JOIN hg_users AS u ON u.user_id = ft.user_id_fk 
                JOIN hg_car_details AS cd ON u.user_id = cd.user_id_fk
                WHERE u.user_id != '$user_id' AND cd.car_type = '$car_type' AND u.user_id != 
                (SELECT blacklist_user_fk FROM hg_black_list WHERE user_id_fk = '$user_id') ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    while ($keys = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $token = $keys['fcm_token'];
                    $title = 'HIRENGO';
                    $message = 'New Job Request Received';
                    $activity_to_open = 'new job';
                    sendPushNotification($token, $title, $message,$activity_to_open);
                    }

                }else{
                    //get all fcm key and send notification (if blacklist table empty)
                    $sql = "SELECT ft.fcm_token from hg_user_notify_token ft 
                    JOIN hg_users AS u ON u.user_id = ft.user_id_fk 
                    JOIN hg_car_details AS cd ON u.user_id = cd.user_id_fk
                    WHERE u.user_id != '$user_id' AND cd.car_type = '$car_type'";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    while ($keys = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                      $token = $keys['fcm_token'];
                      $title = 'HIRENGO';
                      $message = 'New Job Request Received';
                      $activity_to_open = 'new job';
                      sendPushNotification($token, $title, $message,$activity_to_open);
                    }
                }

            }else{
            //if specific car type
                if ($res_black->num_rows > 0) {
                    //get all fcm key and send notification (if blacklist table not empty)
                    $sql = "SELECT ft.fcm_token from hg_user_notify_token ft 
                    JOIN hg_users AS u ON u.user_id = ft.user_id_fk 
                    JOIN hg_car_details AS cd ON u.user_id = cd.user_id_fk
                    WHERE u.user_id != '$user_id' AND cd.car_type = '$car_type' 
                    AND cd.car_type_specific = '$car_type_specific' AND u.user_id != 
                    (SELECT blacklist_user_fk FROM hg_black_list WHERE user_id_fk = '$user_id') ";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);


                    while ($keys = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                       $token = $keys['fcm_token'];
                       $title = 'HIRENGO';
                       $message = 'New Job Request Received';
                       $activity_to_open = 'new job';
                       sendPushNotification($token, $title, $message,$activity_to_open);
                   }
               }else{
                    //get all fcm key and send notification (if blacklist table empty)
                    $sql = "SELECT ft.fcm_token from hg_user_notify_token ft 
                    JOIN hg_users AS u ON u.user_id = ft.user_id_fk 
                    JOIN hg_car_details AS cd ON u.user_id = cd.user_id_fk
                    WHERE u.user_id != '$user_id' AND cd.car_type = '$car_type' 
                    AND cd.car_type_specific = '$car_type_specific'";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    while ($keys = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        $token = $keys['fcm_token'];
                        $title = 'HIRENGO';
                        $message = 'New Job Request Received';
                        $activity_to_open = 'new job';
                        sendPushNotification($token, $title, $message,$activity_to_open);
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
            <script>
                function callDispatch()
                {
                    nIntervId = window.setInterval(myCallback, 5000);
                    var baseUrl = document.location.origin;
                    function myCallback()
                    {
                        var user_id = '<?=$GLOBALS["user_id"];?>';
                        var job_id = '<?=$job_id;?>';
                        $.ajax({
                            url: baseUrl+'/android/selectDriverForJobResult.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType : 'json',
                            data: {'user_id': user_id, 'job_id': job_id} ,
                            success: function(response) {
                                clearInterval(nIntervId); 
                                var resp = response.toString();
                                if (resp.includes('true') === true) 
                                {
                                    console.log('true'+ resp); 
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    console.log(resp);
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(response)
                            {
                                console.log('Error in ajax'+response.statusText);
                                clearInterval(nIntervId);   
                            }     
                        });
                    }
                }
                callDispatch();
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    } else{
        echo json_encode(Array('message' => 'error job post'));
    }
$conn->close();
?>
```

[image]

Comment: You really should rethink your logic here because using using AJAX in this way, in an API will only result in frustration.

Comment: You can make an ajax call here in php, why you need to call as a separate javascript function

Comment: @JayBlanchard i have to call the second file after 2 minutes without using the sleep() of php because that will cause busy wait on server. What else can i do?